# Is it possible to search some keywords in title only?

Tags: support, search, title

I am trying to search the posts whose titles contains some keywords, e.g. "all types of".

So, I used this tag and a pair of quotation mark ""

> title: "all types of"

[image]

the results shown above are what I want, though, below are not

[image]

Is it possible to search some keywords in title only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, possible.

You need to prefix `title` **without the space** as in, [`title:"all types of"`](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22all+types+of%22)

[image]

Please refer the [Advanced Search page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess the previous failure is due to the space between the colon mark and quotation mark